# Angular 2: Storing User Data in Firebase Database AFTER Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to create users in my Firebase database after authentication. Here's an example:

Component:

```
regGoogle() {               
    this.af.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Redirect,
    })
    //Need to invoke this AFTER auth
    this.memberCreationService.regGoogle(
        auth.auth.providerData[0].email,
        auth.auth.providerData[0].displayName,
        auth.auth.providerData[0].photoURL,
        auth.uid
     )
}
```

My service:

```
regGoogle(
    email: string, displayName: string, photoUrl: string, uid: string) {
    let member: Object = {
        email: email,
        displayName: displayName,
        picture: photoURL
    }
    this.af.database.object(`/members/${uid}`).update(member)       
}
```

Originally, I was invoking `regGoogle()` in my service's constructor, just for basic functionality like this:

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        this.auth = auth;
        if (auth) {
            this.regGoogle(
                auth.auth.providerData[0].email,
                auth.auth.providerData[0].displayName,
                auth.auth.providerData[0].photoURL,
                auth.uid
            )
        } 
})
```

Obviously, that's not very good for a real app. For one thing, it indiscriminately invokes `regGoogle()`. But my specific issue is that the user is created regardless of whether I want to login or register. Since, there is no register method on auth for providers, this makes it necessary to determine whether the user already exists somewhere in whatever method you use to register/login.

#### Update:

So the goal was to have separate methods for each provider and also for whether I was trying to log in or to register. The reason for this was to avoid overwriting and existing user. Not, only was this overly complicated, this required that the action for each was imperatively executed and didn't seem to work with the async FirebaseAuthState.

I ended up consolidating the registration/login methods and invoking them in my service's constructor as soon as the service received an authstate emission, as I was doing before, but checking whether the user existed within the registration/login method.

```
loginProvider() {       
    let member: Object = {
        email: this.auth.auth.providerData[0].email,
        displayName: this.auth.auth.providerData[0].displayName,
        picture: this.auth.auth.providerData[0].photoURL
    }
    this.af.database.object(`members/${this.auth.uid}`)
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data.$value === null) {              
            this.af.database.object(`members/${this.auth.uid}`).update(member)
            this.router.navigate(['member-creation'])
        } else {
            console.log('Thanks for logging in, ' + this.auth.auth.providerData[0].displayName)
            this.router.navigate(['threads/featured'])
        }
    })  
}
```

I'd love to hear any opinions on this implementation.

Comment: I am new too! Forgive my ignorance, but is that regGoogle required? I kind of do what you do, but I am using simply `auth.displayName` for example. The sign in method is irrelevant in this case for that basic data.

Comment: The Firebase methods are sufficient to  get a user registered and authenticated, but if you want to add that user to your Firebase database, you'll need to define some sort of action to do that.

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry, we have much the same code.  Once Auth happens, I use the state property (your `auth` property) to go and subscribe to an inner observable `let user$ = this.af.database.object("/members/${auth.auth.uid}")`. I then check to see if that record exists from this call.  If not, I use `auth.auth.email, auth.auth.displayName and auth.auth.photoURL`. (I don't care who provides it) in order to build my `member` object, and then I send it over with `user$.set(member)`.

Comment: Yeah, it's the asynchronous part that's killing me here. `regGoogle` is imperative in nature. I want to specify the action taken when the user registers with Google, but the action is always taken before the auth state is received. I was just doing it in the constructor before, but I want to do it imperatively somehow... this is probably a result of not quite understanding observables yet.

Comment: This is probably the result of bad implementation on my part. Maybe I need to rethink the way I distinguish registration from login. The idea was to use a separate method for each. I have separate views for each process.